# Obtain marginal CDF from joint CDF through simulation

Tags: matlab, simulation, probability, cdf

How can I evaluate the marginal cumulative distribution function of a set of random variables for which I do not have the CDF in closed form. I can, however, simulate from a joint distribution involving this set of variables.

To be more specific, assume I want to evaluate the CDF of `(X_1,X_2)` but I only have a way to simulate from `(X_1,X_2,X_3)`.

Obviously I can approximate the CDF of `(X_1,X_2,X_3)` by obtaining a large number of simulations and checking how many observations fall below the desired threshold. But how to get the CDF of `(X_1,X_2)`?. Can I just simply throw `X_3` away and use the same procedure as for the joint PDF?

Comment: This is a question better asked on [stats.SE]

Comment: Has been asked and answered on Cross-Validation, throwing $X_3$ away is indeed the solution.